# trouble with highchart and .clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I don't understand how I'm supposed to use jQuery .clone() when i'm cloning an highchart.
I know that .clone() doesn't link the methods on objects. So the clone of the highchart looked correct, but you couldn't interact with it anymore.
SO, I've been trying the following :

```
function clonage(src){
    var clone = src.clone(false);
    if (clone.hasClass("highchart")){
        clone.highcharts({});
    }
}
```

By doing this, I've got back the interactions with the chart (the chart is blank), but this is destroying the original of the clone (ie src) which is now only a blank widget.
I would like to be able to recreate the exact same chart without embedding all the chart information to recreate it.
If anyone has an idea in order to do this?

Comment: You need to create new chart in the i.e object when you woud like to have cloned highcharts. Similiar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967149/open-highcharts-in-modal-window

Comment: yeah, it's working, but that's a solution I would have preferred to avoid :/

Comment: Honestly I dont know better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jquery .extend ? Seems to work for me.

```
var clone = $.extend(true, {}, $obj);
```