# Highcharts click event with HighSlide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highslide

I am using  high charts, in the chart configuration for click event I would like to generate a pop up or modal. I am able to do that using HighSlide, here is the code for that

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                slicedOffset: 0,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                stacking: 'normal',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (e) {

                                                            hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                                                pageOrigin: {
                                                                    x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                                                    y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                                                                },
                                                                headingText: 'test', //this.series.name,
                                                                maincontentText: this.y + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test();"> Click </a>',
                                                                width: 200
                                                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
```

I am able to open the pop up, but in the pop up I have a link which is supposed execute js function. I have the function in the file same as the above code. But it is not performing any click function. Anybody point me where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: it is possibly a scope issue. It all depends where your function is located, and if it is accessible from where you are trying to execute it. Do you have any errors in the console? I would guess you have a 'test() is not a function...' error.  If you can post an example on fiddle, that would be helpful

Comment: See similiar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967149/open-highcharts-in-modal-window/15020235#15020235